# what does name="data[user][pass] in input tag means?

Tags: php, html

I found this inside an input tag of a website:

```
... name="data[user][pass]" ...
```

What does this mean? How can I make this with php in the tag attribute? and how can I read this?

Comment: I would answer this, but I'd get downvoted. ** It means that the user is using `asp`, `php`, or some other `java` or `C...` code to access an `array` that they have stored on their `database`. Or they are retarded and had that information feed to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If present in an `<input>` tag and when the corresponding form gets submitted to a PHP script it can be accessed like:

```
$_GET['data']['user']['pass']; // or
$_POST['data']['user']['pass'];
```

Depending on the request method.

Comment: thanks you, What is supposed to write php script inside tag "name="

Comment: @user3258732 I don't quite understand what you're asking me.

Comment: i means what suppose i write in "name" attribute to read by php script

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['data']['user']['pass']; // or
$_POST['data']['user']['pass']; // or
$_REQUEST['data']['user']['pass'];
```